# Create new array from an existing array attributes

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I am trying to create a new array out of limited values from an existing array. In the example below `LargeArray` contains many attributes – year, books, gdp and control. Lets say I want to create a new array that would only include year and gdp.

```
var LargeArray = [
    {year:1234, books:1200, gdp:1200, control:1200}, 
    {year:1235, books:1201, gdp:1200, control:1200}, 
    {year:1236, books:1202, gdp:1200, control:1200}
];
```

The new array I am trying to get, would look like this:

```
var NewArray = [
    {year:1234, gdp:1200},
    {year:1235, gdp:1200},
    {year:1236, gdp:1200}
];
```

Comment: I would like to use Jquery to create the new array, i am not sure if map function would help. If it's better with plain javaScript its great too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use [$.map()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/)

```
var LargeArray = [{year:1234, books:1200, gdp:1200, control:1200}, {year:1235, books:1201, gdp:1200, control:1200}, {year:1236, books:1202, gdp:1200, control:1200}, {year:1237, books:1203, gdp:1200, control:1200}, {year:1238, books:1204, gdp:1200, control:1200}];
var NewArray = $.map(LargeArray, function (value) {
    return {
        year: value.year,
        gdp: value.gdp
    }
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/vQ82m/)

Comment: I just looked up `$.map` and it mentioned running the array through `$.makeArray` -- would this be relevant here?

Comment: @RUJordan no it is not since the OP has an actual array

Answer (score 3):

Using [**Array.prototype.map**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```
var newArray = largeArray.map(function(obj) {
  return { year: obj.year, gdp: obj.gdp };
});
```

Note: `Array.prototype.map` is a recent addition. Use the shim from MDN to support older browsers.

[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/xNJEV/)